# Transforming multi response probabilities to logit space

Tags: multiple-regression

How can I transform multi response probabilities to a logit space such that:
$$ \pi_{i,j}=\frac{exp(p_{i,j})}{\sum^J_{k=1}exp(p_{i,k})}$$
For the binary response this transformation is: 
$$ p_{i}=log(\frac{\pi_{i}}{1-\pi_{i}})$$
But is there a formula that generalizes to multinomial respons or does I have to resort to numerical optimization in order to calculate the transformation?

Example: A multi response probability could come out of a multiresponse model so there might be 3 outcomes with probabilities $\Pi=[0.576,0.212,0.212]$ which could correspond to the following logit space vector $P=[1,0,0]$.

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed explanation of what "multi response probabilities" might be and why the transformation you seek isn't exactly the same as the one you write down for $\pi_{i,j}$?